# Why do I have to iterate the SQLAlchemy object to return it in FastAPI?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

This `GET` endpoint doesn't work:

```py
@app.get("/question/", response_model=list[schemas.QuizSchema])
def get_questions(db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    quiz = db.query(models.Quiz).all()
    return jsonable_encoder(quiz)
```

It raises the following error:

```
raise ValidationError(errors, field.type_)
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 3 validation errors for QuizSchema
response -> 0 -> category
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
response -> 0 -> answer
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
response -> 0 -> question
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

But this code works pretty well:

```py
@app.get("/question/", response_model=list[schemas.QuizSchema])
def get_questions(db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    quiz = db.query(models.Quiz).all()
    for x in quiz:
        print(x.id, x.category.id, x.answer[0].id, x.question.id)
    return jsonable_encoder(quiz)
```

I really don't understand what's going on.

I used a breakpoint before and after the `for`-loop like that:

```py
@app.get("/question/", response_model=list[schemas.QuizSchema])
def get_questions(db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    quiz = db.query(models.Quiz).all()
    breakpoint()
    for x in quiz:
        print(x.id, x.category.id, x.answer[0].id, x.question.id)
    breakpoint()
    return jsonable_encoder(quiz)
```

That's the result:

```
# FIRST BREAKPOINT
(Pdb) quiz
[<models.Quiz object at 0x7fb81957c5e0>]
(Pdb) jsonable_encoder(quiz)
[{'id': 2}]
(Pdb) continue
2 3 1 1
> /backend/main.py(29)get_questions()
-> return jsonable_encoder(quiz)

#SECOND BREAKPOINT
(Pdb) quiz
[<models.Quiz object at 0x7fb81957c5e0>]
(Pdb) jsonable_encoder(quiz)
[{'id': 2, 'category': {'quiz_category_id': 2, 'id': 3, 'name': 'foo'}, 'answer': [{'name': 'zdecydowanie nie', 'value': -2, 'id': 1}, {'name': 'raczej nie', 'value': -1, 'id': 2}, {'name': 'nie wiem', 'value': 0, 'id': 3}, {'name': 'raczej tak', 'value': 1, 'id': 4}, {'name': 'zdecydowanie tak', 'value': 2, 'id': 5}], 'question': {'name': 'bar', 'quiz_question_id': 2, 'id': 1}}]
(Pdb)
```

My SQLAlchemy model looks like this:

```py
class Quiz(Base):
    __tablename__ = "quiz"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    category: Mapped["Category"] = relationship(back_populates="quiz_category")
    answer: Mapped[list[Answer]] = relationship(secondary=quiz_answer)
    question: Mapped["Question"] = relationship(back_populates="quiz_question")
```

Comment: can you show how `models.Quiz` look like?

Comment: looks like you don't have any form of eager loading set, can you try adding an extra arg `lazy='selectin'` to all the three relationships you have and check if it works

Comment: What's your definition for `QuizSchema`? Have you defined it with `orm_mode = True` so that it attempts to load attributes as well? There's also no need to call `jsonable_encoder` yourself, FastAPI will handle that for you by default (and uses the schema for the response model for how to convert/which fields to include)

Comment: @MatsLindh I can't edit my post so ugly I'll paste here. I had defined orm_mode=True. "There's also no need to call jsonable_encoder yourself, FastAPI will handle that for you by default (and uses the schema for the response model for how to convert/which fields to include)" I totally agree with you but in this case I had problems with rendering and looked for different ways to do it :)

Comment: QuizSchema:  id: int
    category: CategorySchema
    answer: list[AnswerSchema]
    question: QuestionSchema

Answer (score 0):

Schema should have config class where it should have `orm_mode = True`:

```
class QuizSchema(BaseModel):
  .... field 
  class Config(): 
     orm_mode = True
```

Comment: Nope, the problem was with lazy loading.